# SQL view for displaying a collection, with any associated related records by employee

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, performance, refactoring

I am writing a training administration system and need to display a list of all training course types held in a table for each employee in a given team.

For each of those training courses I then want to look at a booking table and get the latest booking for that employee and course type combo. Even if no booking exists I still want to pull back each course type for each employee. (Albeit with nulls for the booking fields). Bookings join to employee on booking.empID to employee.id and booking links to coursetype on booking.courseId to courseType.id.

I want the result to be grouped by employee.

I have managed to get this working by creating a view model in MVC, BUT even on my test data with 8 employees, 10 course types and a handfull of bookings I am seeing load times of 6-7 seconds. I assume that my view model is wildly inefficient.

These are the classes I am using on my VM:

```
public class TeamMemberTraining()
{
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<trainingSet> Trainingset { get; set; }
}

public class trainingSet()
{
   public int templateId { get; set; }
   public string templateName { get; set; }      
   public TrainingCourseBooking LastBooking { get; set; }
   public TrainingCourseBooking FutureBooking { get; set; }
}
```

My dataset is build in my repository in the following way:

```
 public List<TeamMemberTraining> GetPersonalHistory(int id)
    {
        var teamMatrix = new List<TeamMemberTraining>();
        var teamMembers = GetProfileIdsByTeam(teamID); //Int list of employee id's
        foreach (var teamMemberin teamMembers)
        {
            var empMatrix = new TeamMemberTraining();
            var empRecord = _entities.employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == emp);
            empMatrix.trainingSet = GetPersonalHistory(emp);
            empMatrix.UserId = empRecord.Id;
            empMatrix.UserName = empRecord.forename + " " + empRecord.surname;
            teamMatrix.Add(empMatrix);
        }
}


 public IEnumerable<trainingSet> GetPersonalHistory(int id)
    {
        var matrix = new List<trainingSet>();
        var courses = (from a in _entities.courseTypes
            select a).ToList();
        var employee = (from a in _entities.employees
            where a.Id == id
            select a).FirstOrDefault();
        foreach (var course in courses)
        {
            var matrixItem = new trainingSet
            {
                templateId = course.Id,
                templateName = course.description,
             };
            var history = (from a in _entities.TrainingCourseBookings
                where a.templateId == courseType.Id && a.employeeId == id && a.certificateIssued
                orderby a.Id descending
                select a).FirstOrDefault();
            if (history != null)
            {
                matrixItem.LastBooking = history;
            }

            var future = (from a in _entities.TrainingCourseBookings
                where a.templateId == courseType.Id && a.employeeId == id && a.TrainingCourse.courseDate >= DateTime.Now
                orderby a.Id descending
                select a).FirstOrDefault();
            if (future != null)
            {
                matrixItem.FutureBooking = future;
            }

            matrix.Add(matrixItem);
       }

        return matrix;
    }
```

This gives me my list of all courses, by user, with bookings shown if they exist. It also gives me a whole load of slow loading times with all the nesting.

Can anyone offer me any better ways of achieving this?

Many many thanks

Comment: The view model is not where you are spending your time. I would look into how you are building up your dataset. Specifically, you are materializing each table multiple times and you are executing all of your queries against these local collections. Also, while it is not costing you any additional performance, the expression```(from a in _entities.courseTypes select a).ToList()``` is semantically identical to ```_entities.courseTypes.ToList()```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```cs
   IEnumerable<TrainingSet> GetPersonalHistory(int id)
   {
        var employee = _entities.employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
        var results =  
            from course in _entities.courseTypes
            let applicableBookings = 
                from booking in _entities.TrainingCourseBookings
                where booking.employeeOd == id
                where booking.templateId == course.courseType.Id 
                orderby booking.Id descending
                select booking
            let history = applicableBookings.FirstOrDefault(b => b.certificateIssued)
            let future = applicableBookings.FirstOrDefault(b => b.TrainingCourse.courseData >= DateTime.Now)
            select new TrainingSet 
            {
               TemplateId = course.Id,
               TemplateName = course.description,   
               LastBooking = history,
               FutureBooking = future
            };
        return results.ToList();
    }
```